# HTML Drag and Drop without upload functionality

Tags: javascript, html, frontend, smb

I am curious if it is possible with HTML to allow users to drag-and-drop a folder into my web-app. But instead the files being uploaded I only care about the foldername.
This is for an internal business application that operates on files on shared network storage. Therefore there is no need for an upload - instead I only care for the exact filename. This can be a Windows unc full path, such as \smb-share\foo\foo1
or a Mac path such as /Volumes/foo/foo1.

Thankful for any feedback

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can [Drag and Drop API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API), to have a draggable area, which when a file drag inside, the `drop` event fire and can get the `files` from `event.e.dataTransfer.files`, and you can get the name of each file by iterating over and get `file.name`.

**[EXAMPLE FROM CODEPEN](https://codepen.io/zahedkamal87/pen/PobNNwE)**

```js
var dropzone = document.getElementById('dropzone');
var dropzone_input = dropzone.querySelector('.dropzone-input');
var multiple = dropzone_input.getAttribute('multiple') ? true : false;

['drag', 'dragstart', 'dragend', 'dragover', 'dragenter', 'dragleave', 'drop'].forEach(function(event) {
  dropzone.addEventListener(event, function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
});

dropzone.addEventListener('dragover', function(e) {
  this.classList.add('dropzone-dragging');
}, false);

dropzone.addEventListener('dragleave', function(e) {
  this.classList.remove('dropzone-dragging');
}, false);

dropzone.addEventListener('drop', function(e) {
  this.classList.remove('dropzone-dragging');
  var files = e.dataTransfer.files;
  
  var for_alert = "";
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(files, file => {
    alert(file.name)
  });

  
}, false);

dropzone.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  dropzone_input.click();
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:wght@400;500;700&display=swap');
body {
  font-family: "Roboto";
}
h1 {
  text-align: center;
  margin-bottom: 2rem;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  border-bottom: 2px solid lighten(#6583fe, 15%);
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 400;
}
.dropzone {
  border: 0.2rem dashed #6583fe;
  padding: 2rem;
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
  background-color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  transition: 0.25s background-color ease-in-out;
  cursor: pointer;
  
  &-dragging,
  &:hover {
    background-color: lighten(#6583fe, 28%);
  }
  
  &-icon {
    max-width: 75px;
    display: block;
    margin: 0 auto 1.5rem;
  }
  
  &-input {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<h1>Vanilla JS Drag & Drop upload zone for input file element</h1>

<div class="dropzone" id="dropzone">
    <img class="dropzone-icon" src="https://wickedev.com/wp-content/uploads/2021/02/cloud-uploading.png" />
    
    Drop files or Click here to select files to upload.
    <input type="file" name="files" class="dropzone-input" multiple />
</div>
```